# Unexpected MySQL INT Field Handling On Date Time Input

Tags: mysql, sql, int

I've one of the following table in my DB for which output of 'Show Create Table' is shared:

```
CREATE TABLE `clues_rma_efficacy_triggers` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `data` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `data_type` char(1) NOT NULL,
 `parent_key_id` tinyint(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `child_key_id` tinyint(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `parent_flag` tinyint(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `child_flag` tinyint(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `datetime` int(11) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 UNIQUE KEY `data_child_key` (`data`,`parent_key_id`,`child_key_id`),
 KEY `idx_pki_cf_cki` (`parent_key_id`,`child_flag`,`child_key_id`),
 KEY `idx_pki_pf` (`parent_key_id`,`parent_flag`),
 KEY `idx_cki_cf` (`child_key_id`,`child_flag`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=32436413 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

As you can see, datetime column is int field, in which I'm storing unix_time values. But I'm getting unexpected behavior for one of SELECT query. Step for producing are mentioned below:

1 Sample Insert:

```
INSERT INTO `clues_rma_efficacy_triggers` (`data`,`data_type`,`parent_key_id`,`datetime`) VALUES (1234568197,'R',89,1522933144);

mysql> select * from clues_rma_efficacy_triggers where data = 1234568197;
+----------+------------+-----------+---------------+--------------+-------------+------------+------------+--------------+
| id       | data       | data_type | parent_key_id | child_key_id | parent_flag | child_flag | datetime   | deleted_flag |
+----------+------------+-----------+---------------+--------------+-------------+------------+------------+--------------+
| 34905336 | 1234568197 | R         |            89 |            0 |           0 |          0 | 1522933144 |            0 |
+----------+------------+-----------+---------------+--------------+-------------+------------+------------+--------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

Below query should not fetch result, yet it is fetching result(it is ignoring complete datetime clause and working on parent_key_id and parent_flag)

```
SELECT * , from_unixtime( datetime ) FROM clues_rma_efficacy_triggers WHERE datetime BETWEEN (NOW( ) - ( 86400 *30 )) AND NOW( ) AND parent_key_id =89 AND parent_flag =0 LIMIT 200;

mysql> SELECT * , from_unixtime( datetime ) FROM clues_rma_efficacy_triggers WHERE datetime BETWEEN (NOW( ) - ( 86400 *30 )) AND NOW( ) AND parent_key_id =89 AND parent_flag =0 LIMIT 200 ;
+----------+------------+-----------+---------------+--------------+-------------+------------+------------+--------------+---------------------------+
| id       | data       | data_type | parent_key_id | child_key_id | parent_flag | child_flag | datetime   | deleted_flag | from_unixtime( datetime ) |
+----------+------------+-----------+---------------+--------------+-------------+------------+------------+--------------+---------------------------+
| 34905336 | 1234568197 | R         |            89 |            0 |           0 |          0 | 1522933144 |            0 | 2018-04-05 18:29:04       |
+----------+------------+-----------+---------------+--------------+-------------+------------+------------+--------------+---------------------------+
1 row in set, 2 warnings (0.01 sec)
```

Warning Received:

```
mysql> SHOW WARNINGS;
+---------+------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Level   | Code | Message                                                               |
+---------+------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Warning | 1292 | Incorrect datetime value: '1522933144' for column 'datetime' at row 1 |
| Warning | 1292 | Incorrect datetime value: '20180407571651'                            |
+---------+------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

This is the output when I convert first clause of between part:

```
mysql> SELECT (NOW( ) - ( 86400 *30 ));
+--------------------------+
| (NOW( ) - ( 86400 *30 )) |
+--------------------------+
|           20180407571651 |
+--------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Second clause of Between is of course current date. 
So parsed query should become:

```
SELECT * , from_unixtime( datetime ) FROM clues_rma_efficacy_triggers WHERE DATETIME BETWEEN 20180407571651 AND '2018-04-10 16:07:00' AND parent_key_id =89 AND parent_flag =0 LIMIT 200;
```

which, course is not fetching result.

```
mysql> SELECT * , from_unixtime( datetime ) FROM clues_rma_efficacy_triggers WHERE DATETIME BETWEEN 20180407571651 AND '2018-04-10 16:07:00' AND parent_key_id =89 AND parent_flag =0 LIMIT 200; 
Empty set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

Warning Received:

```
mysql> SHOW WARNINGS;                                                                                                                                                                          +---------+------+---------------------------------------------------------+
| Level   | Code | Message                                                 |
+---------+------+---------------------------------------------------------+
| Warning | 1292 | Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: '2018-04-10 16:07:00' |
+---------+------+---------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

I'm confused how first query is working. `Where` clause contains only `AND` conditions. It should fail right away, since datetime clause is not right in parsed query. Verison Output:

```
mysql> SELECT VERSION();
+-----------------+
| VERSION()       |
+-----------------+
| 10.1.12-MariaDB |
+-----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

[image]

Comment: Did you notice that the query that should not fetch result has generated warnings? `1 row in set, 2 warnings (0.01 sec)`  use `SHOW WARNINGS:` to see them.. post the warning records here might have something to do why the record was selected..

Comment: @RaymondNijland , warnings updated in question description. First query Warning suggests that, query is being parsed as like second query. Yet this is fetching result.

Comment: Check mine answer

Comment: @HoneyBadger, it is because of version. I executed select version in same fiddle, output was 5.6.39. I've also tried the same on 1 other mysql version (5.7.21-0ubuntu0.16.04.1), there too it was not reproducible. But yes, this is reproducible on 10.0.24-MariaDB-wsrep as well as 10.1.12-MariaDB. Tested on both.